# How to find an unnamed button belonging to a certain h2 entry XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, xpath

(I am a bit of a StackOverflow newbie, so please forgive any beginner mistakes and let me know what to improve in the future)

I am trying to select the highlighted button in the appended picture.

**Problem**:

- There are many buttons of this kind all using the same description and XPath. So as far as I can tell there is no way of telling them apart by their cssSelector or XPath

Possible solution:

- The h2 above the button contains a differentiable description of the button I need to select. So can I basically navigate to said h2 and then select the specific button belonging to it?
  **-> How to code it?**
  Are there easier ways to do this?

So far I know basic element selection as seen in this code sample:

```
    WebElement loginElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-submitBtn']"));
    loginElement.click();
```

[image: html sample]

Comment: welcome to the community. You wrote good first question post here. Keep it up & accept answer which helped you. Happy teting!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

- You can use different advance locator strategy using xpath which selenium supports. There would be many but mentioning few below:
- **Option 1: XPath using ‘AND’ & ‘OR’**

  - The ‘AND’ & ‘OR’ operators in the XPath selector in Selenium are used when locating a WebElement based on certain condition sets
  - In the case of ‘AND,’ both the conditions should be True
  - On the other hand, either of the two conditions can be true for ‘OR’
    in operator XPath
- **Option 2 : Relative locators** if you are ***using Selenium 4***

**How to implement it?**

- **Option 1:**

  - Using AND

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@type='button' AND @name='select-organisation-button']"
```

- Using Tag with Class, and Attribute value

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2.MuiButton-text[name=\"select-organisation-button\"]"));
```

- **Option 2**:

```
targetted_button_locator = locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "h2").below({By.NAME: "select-organisation-button"})
```