# How to find the find an element by Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="fl">
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Cadastro</h3>
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Movimento</h3>
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Consulta</h3>
```

I need to click on "Consulta", but I can't.
I already tried driver.find_element(By.("CLASS_NAME, XPATH, TAG_NAME, LINK_TEXT,etc") but none is working.

Some elements I've tried:

```
driver.find_element(BY.XPATH, "//*[@id='conteudo"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/h3").click()

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fl')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'colMenu')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'submenu')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! Thanks for adding the HTML. Can you also provide the exact "CLASS_NAME, XPATH, TAG_NAME, LINK_TEXT" you tried?

Comment: I try: driver.find_element(BY.XPATH, "//*[@id='conteudo"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/h3").click()

Comment: Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fl')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")

Comment: Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'colMenu')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")

Comment: Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'submenu')))).select_by_visible_text("Consulta")

Comment: I've added your element attempts to the main question.

Comment: @Matheus welcome!
Check solution on below link, might help you to fix this quickly
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51042/how-to-find-an-unnamed-button-belonging-to-a-certain-h2-entry-xpath/51043#51043

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below XPath expression:

`//h3[contains(text(),"Consulta")]`

**Assumption:** The text **Consulta** appears only once in the website

**XPath explanation:** This relative XPath searches all the `h3` tags which contain text `Consulta`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code I created as per the information you provided:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fl">
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Cadastro</h3>
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Movimento</h3>
<div class="colMenu">
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Consulta</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

It has been automated using Java, Selenium and [TMT Testing Utilities](https://www.theminitools.com/tools/TMT-Testing-Utilities.html) library with this code:

```
package Demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import com.theminitools.TestingUtilities.Utilities;

public class Demo implements Utilities{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "/home/staah/Tools/Java/geckodriver");
            u.setBrowser("chrome");
            u.go("file:///home/milin/eclipse-workspace/Demo/resource/index.html");
            u.wait(5);

//          // your code goes here
            WebElement menuLink = u.find("xpath", "//div[@class='colMenu']/h3[@class='submenu' and contains(text(),'Consulta')]");
            u.click(menuLink);
//          // your code goes here
            
            u.closeBrowser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get the script to click the 'Consulta' menu item.

You can translate this code to Python. It should be something like this,

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///home/milin/eclipse-workspace/Demo/resource/index.html")

menu_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='colMenu']/h3[@class='submenu' and contains(text(),'Consulta')]")
menu_link.click()

driver.close()
```

I'm not sure of Python as I haven't worked with it.